# Converting a complex struct to a simple json

Tags: json, go

**Background**

I have a struct that I have been passing to users as a json via an API. This works.

I am now trying to send the same struct as an object that my UI can easily convert to a csv and allow the user to download.

I have code that works on the UI to convert simple objects to a CSV. So I can send an object where the values are just integers or strings no problem. But, my struct has values that are objects and arrays. So, I am trying to find a way to convert my complex json object to a simpler one. The simpler object should only have values with either no quotes like an int or just one set of quotes on the outside like a string.

**Question**

How do I convert a golang struct into a json that has "simple" values (string, bool, int but not array or object with more quotes)?

**Example**

For instance this code converts user to a json with the formatting:

```
{
 "Name":"Frank",
 "Friends":[{"Age":10,"Name":"Joe"}, {"Age":12,"Name":"John"}],
 "FavSnacks":["apple","orange"]
}
```

, but I would like the formatting

```
 {
  "Name":"Frank",
  "Friends":"[{'Age':10,'Name':'Joe'},{'Age':12,'Name':'John'}]",
  "FavSnacks":"['apple','orange']"
 }
```

or

```
 {
  "Name":"Frank",
  "Friends":"[{Age:10, Name:Joe},{Age:12,Name:John}]",
  "FavSnacks":"[apple, orange]"
 }
```

Here is the code I have

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type User struct {
    Name string
    Friends []Friend
    FavSnacks []string
}

type Friend struct {
    Age int
    Name string
}

func main() {
    user := &User{Name: "Frank", FavSnacks: []string{"apple","orange"}, Friends: []Friend{{Age: 10, Name: "Joe"},{Age: 12, Name: "John"}} }
    b, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
     
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

**Notes**

1. I am using this site: https://play.golang.org/ to test the code above.
2. It would be great if the function for this worked by looping through all struct fields since in real life I have a struct with around 30 fields some of which are structs that have nested structs.

Comment: @Inian Yes I just want a "flat" json. I believe that they are valid json. They just have a string value where the string contains [ and { characters.

Comment: You have literal strings now, the `[` and `{` i.e. array and object traits of JSON are not valid anymore. Is that what you need?

Comment: @Inian Yes, its for a csv file where the header will be "FavSnacks" and the value will be [apple, orange]. If I leave in the double quotes, it ruins the column alignment on excel etc.

Comment: You do not want JSON, so do not use `encoding/json`

Comment: @EmilePels My goal is still to pass this object through an API, the type that the API sends is of type application/json. This is why I am keeping the type json. Should I be looking into changing the API to pass differing types?

Comment: @Romulus  And the person who is going to use your csv is going to have a hell of a job parsing those merged columns back into the separate values. Why use csv if your data is not tabular but complex? Should you not just allow the user to download it as json or perhaps xml instead of csv?

Comment: @Bazzz honestly, I know, I made a json button, it works. They said they like CSV's and now here I am making a 2nd button that allows for csv download.

Comment: @Romulus there is no way a dog is ever going to become a cat. It makes no sense asking for a cat when you visit a kennel. With all respect, but perhaps you should explain your client that asking for csv for complex data is "the wrong question". And if they persist, I suggest making a csv file with just one column in which you put the json data for that record. Yes it is hard to use, but your halfway approach is even harder to use on the client's end, because it looks like csv but it sometimes is not.

Answer (score 0):

Build a map with the values you want to marshal. Use the reflect API to iterate through the fields in the struct and collect the values in a map.  If the value of the field is a slice or struct, then encode the field to JSON and use that value in the map.  Return the map encoded to JSON.

```
func marshalFlat(value interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(value))
    t := v.Type()

    // Collect all fields in this map.
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        sf := t.Field(i)
        if sf.PkgPath != "" {
            // skip unexported
            continue
        }
        f := reflect.Indirect(v.Field(i))
        switch f.Kind() {
        case reflect.Slice, reflect.Struct:
            // Encode slices and structs as JSON and use
            // that JSON as the value of the field.
            p, err := json.Marshal(f.Interface())
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            m[sf.Name] = string(p)
        default:
            // User other types as is.
            m[sf.Name] = f.Interface()
        }
    }
    return json.Marshal(m)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dBX5o3WLLqP)

Answer (score 0):

Just implement Marshaler interface :)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Friends Friends `json:"friends"`
    FavSnacks FavSnacks `json:"fav_snacks"`
}

type Friend struct {
    Age int `json:"age"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Friends []Friend

func (f *Friends) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type FriendsAux []Friend

    friendsAux := FriendsAux(*f)

    marshal, err := json.Marshal(friendsAux)
    if err != nil {
        return []byte{}, nil
    }
    escapedMarshal := strings.ReplaceAll(string(marshal), `"`, `'`)

    jsonToString := fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, escapedMarshal)

    return []byte(jsonToString), nil
}

type FavSnacks []string

func (f *FavSnacks) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type FavSnacksAux []string

    favSnacksAux := FavSnacksAux(*f)

    marshal, err := json.Marshal(favSnacksAux)
    if err != nil {
        return []byte{}, nil
    }
    escapedMarshal := strings.ReplaceAll(string(marshal), `"`, `'`)

    jsonToString := fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, escapedMarshal)

    return []byte(jsonToString), nil
}


func main() {
    user := &User{Name: "Frank", FavSnacks: []string{"apple","orange"}, Friends: []Friend{{Age: 10, Name: "Joe"},{Age: 12, Name: "John"}} }
    b, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gThG4mx0ogf